# How to convert wide dataframe to long based on similar column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe like this

[image]

and i want to convert it to below dataframe

[image]

i am not sure how to use  pd.wide_to_long function here

**below is the dataset for creating dataframe:**

```py
Date, IN:Male teacher ,IN:Male engineer, IN: Male Atronaut , IN:female teacher ,IN:female engineer, IN: female Atronaut ,GB:Male teacher ,GB:Male engineer, GB: Male Atronaut,GB:female teacher ,GB:female engineer, GB: female Atronaut
20220405,25,29,5,41,23,23,12,23,34,11,22,34
20220404,21,29,4,40,23,22,12,23,32,10,23,34
```

Comment: please include your data as text (preferably its constructor dictionary) rather than as image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `Date` column to `index` and for all another columns remove possible traling spaces by [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), then replace spaces to `:` and last split by one or more `:` to `MultiIndex`, so possible reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for new columns names created by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Date')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.strip().str.replace('\s+', ':').str.split('[:]+', expand=True)

df1 = df1.stack([0,1]).rename_axis(['Date','Symbol','Gender']).reset_index()
print (df1)
       Date Symbol  Gender  Atronaut  engineer  teacher
0  20220405     GB    Male        34        23       12
1  20220405     GB  female        34        22       11
2  20220405     IN    Male         5        29       25
3  20220405     IN  female        23        23       41
4  20220404     GB    Male        32        23       12
5  20220404     GB  female        34        23       10
6  20220404     IN    Male         4        29       21
7  20220404     IN  female        22        23       40
```

Answer (score 2):

[pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) offers an easy way to abstract the reshaping; in this case it can be solved with a regular expression:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(
    index = 'Date', 
    names_to = ('symbol', 'gender', '.value'), 
    names_pattern = r"(.+):\s*(.+)\s+(.+)",
    sort_by_appearance = True)

       Date symbol  gender  teacher  engineer  Atronaut
0  20220405     IN    Male       25        29         5
1  20220405     IN  female       41        23        23
2  20220405     GB    Male       12        23        34
3  20220405     GB  female       11        22        34
4  20220404     IN    Male       21        29         4
5  20220404     IN  female       40        23        22
6  20220404     GB    Male       12        23        32
7  20220404     GB  female       10        23        34
```

The regular expression has capture groups, any group paired with `.value` stays as a header, the rest become column values.